# Form not redirecting AngularJS

Tags: angular, angularjs, forms, window

```html
<head>
  <title>Authentication</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>Username:<br>
      <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="username" placeholder="Enter user1" required>
      <span ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>Password:<br>
      <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter secret123" required>
      <span ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <div ng-controller="LoginController" name="myForm" ng-submit="login()">
      <button ng-click="function()">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>

  <script>
    const app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.login = function () {
        if ($scope.username === "user1" && $scope.password === "secret123") {
          $window.location.href = "./infoPage.html";
        } else {
          alert("Invalid username or password!");
        }
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

I am not familiar with angular 1 as a heads-up. I am expecting the $window.location.href = "./infoPage.html"; to take me to that page to display the content of it.

I was expecting for the correct input to be accepted and take me to the page it directs to, but it is just clearing the form when pressing submit and nothing else. Maybe you guys will see bugs that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Use code block ``` in starting and end of your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define routes in route configuration file. like below

```
    {
        state: "test", // you can give any name
        config: {
            url: "/test", // this will be your preferred URL name in your case this will be "/infoPage"
            templateUrl: "app/Modules/test/test.tmpl.html",// this will be your html file path
            controller: "TestCtrl" // this will be your controller name
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

When I see the code have some problem:

1. You miss define **ng-app="myApp"** for angularjs. So when you click **button submit** function **login** does not run. Form only clear input and **add param to url**
2. You use **$window.location.href** but not add directive **$window** so angular will not underfine (I will update code for you below) or you can use **window.location.href** of js
3. Change **ng-click="function()"** to **ng-click="login()"**

I have update code for you

```
<head>
<title>Authentication</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp"><form>
<p>Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="username" placeholder="Enter user1" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
  </span>
</p>
<p>Password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter secret123" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
  </span>
</p>
<div ng-controller="LoginController" name="myForm">
    <button ng-click="login()">Submit</button>
</div>
  </form>
 <script>
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        if ($scope.username === "user1" && $scope.password === "secret123") {
            $window.location.href = "./infoPage.html";
        } else {
            alert("Invalid username or password!");
        }
    };
});
</script>
</body>
```

*note*: you will need to edit the validation as you want